# Which dependencies for serialization should I use?

Tags: kotlin

I want to do [this manual](https://medium.com/@gurpreetsk/getting-started-with-kotlin-serialization-3315c59bafb2). There's a [link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#setup) to install dependencies, but gradle's mad because of these dependencies. It doesn't want version numbers there. When I remove them It can't find plugins in sources. Then I find another manual. For this I should add some classpath to "project-level" gradle. When I do that my gradle syncs, but there are conflicts with implementations. For one manual I should add this

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.0"
```

For another this one

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.20.0"
```

Whem I use one of them my projects can't use Json keyword, but when I use different one I can't use JsonConfiguration. Together it doesn't compile.

There are many words I wrote, sorry for that. Just give me normal dependencies for groovy gradle.

Comment: This is described in details in the [readme](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#gradle). You need to add the classpath and the gradle plugin.

Comment: @Nicolas I already did it. In this case I can't use JsonConfiguration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has been a lot of changes recently with the release of the stable version. As stated in the [release notes](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/1.0.0-RC/CHANGELOG.md#100-rc--2020-08-17):

> `Json` constructor is replaced with `Json {}` builder function, `JsonConfiguration` is deprecated in favor of `Json {}` builder

Your tutorial is outdated. I suggest you read the [official docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/1.0.0-RC/docs/serialization-guide.md) instead.

As for dependencies, `runtime` was renamed to `json` in 1.0.0. You should have all of these:

```
// build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

// app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$serializationVersion"
}
```

Comment: 1. Can "id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization"" be replaced with "id 'kotlinx-serialization'"? Are these two the same? 2. I saw official docs for lists serialization, but didn't find anything good. It it still possible with new syntax?

Comment: 1. I don't think so, unless you use `apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'` instead of the plugins DSL. 2. Use `Json.encodeToString` on your list as with other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project-level build.gradle, under plugins add

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
        ...........
        ...........
        id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization" version "1.7.10"
    }
```

Go to your app level build-gradle, and add

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    .......
    .......
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}
```

in the sane app-level build-Gradle then add,

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.0"
```